# How to use reduce or fold to encrypt a list of string tokens?

Tags: scala

For example I want to encrypt each token of a sentence and reduce them to a final encrypted text:

```
def convert(str: String) = {
  str + ":"
}

val tokens = "Hi this is a text".split("\\ ").toList

val reduce = tokens.reduce((a, b) => convert(a) + convert(b))
println(reduce)
// result is `Hi:this::is::a::text:`

val fold = tokens.fold("") {
  case (a, b) => convert(a) + convert(b)
}
println(fold)
// result is `:Hi::this::is::a::text:`

val scan = tokens.scan("") {
  case (a, b) => convert(a) + convert(b)
}
println(scan)
// result is List(, :Hi:, :Hi::this:, :Hi::this::is:, :Hi::this::is::a:, :Hi::this::is::a::text:)
```

Assume that convert is an encryption function. So each token should encrypt only once not twice. but fold and reduce and scan reencrypt the encrypted token. I want this desired result `Hi:this:is:a:text:`

Comment: In all these cases you seem to be assuming that a and b are the same. They're not. a is the accumulated result, and b the next token. So you're encrypting the token (b) and adding it to the result,  and next time re-encrypting that result. So miss the convert of a out and things will look a lot better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to encrypt each Token individually, map should work.

```
val tokens = "Hi this is a text".split("\\ ").toList

val encrypted = tokens.map(convert).mkString

println(encrypted) //prints Hi:this:is:a:text:

def convert(str: String) = {
  str + ":"
}
```

Edit: If you want to use a fold:

```
val encrypted = tokens.foldLeft("")((result, token) => result + convert(token))
```

Answer (score 2):

One-liner specialised at this very example,

```
"Hi this is a text" split " " mkString("",":",":")
```

Or

```
val tokens = "Hi this is a text" split " "
val sep = ":"
val encrypted = tokens mkString("",sep,sep)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `fold` or `reduce` will operate on two operands in every step. However you want to encrypt each of the tokens -- which is a **unary** operand. Therefore first you should do a `map` and then either a `fold` or a `reduce`:

```
tokens map(convert)
```

Reduce / Fold:

```
scala> tokens.map(convert).fold("")(_ + _)
res10: String = Hi:this:is:a:text:

scala> tokens.map(convert)reduce(_ + _)
res11: String = Hi:this:is:a:text:
```

Infact you can simply use `mkString` which makes it even more concise:

```
scala> tokens.map(convert).mkString
res12: String = Hi:this:is:a:text:
```

Also you can do the conversion in parallel too (using **par** ):

```
scala> tokens.par.map(convert).mkString
res13: String = Hi:this:is:a:text:

scala> tokens.par.map(convert)reduce(_ + _)
res14: String = Hi:this:is:a:text:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is how `reduce` and `fold` works. You can learn from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408881/1275303)

As for you question, `fold` can help:

```
"Hi this is a text".split("\\ ").fold("") { (a, b) => a + convert(b) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version with the code cleaned up and unnecessary conversions removed:

```
def convert(str: String) = str + :

val tokens = "Hi this is a text" split " "
val encrypted = (tokens map convert) mkString " "
```

**mkString** could be seen as a specialized Version of reduce (or fold) for Strings.

If for some reason, you don't want to use mkString the code would look like this:

```
def convert(str: String) = str + :

val tokens = "Hi this is a text" split " "
val encrypted = (tokens map convert) reduce (_ + _)
```

Or shortend with fold

```
val encrypted = "Hi this is a text".split(" ").foldLeft ("") { case (accum, str) => accum + convert(str) }
```