# Scala reduce on Point class

Tags: scala, reduce

I cannot get the `Point` class to search for the `x` coordinate maximum with one `reduce` operation (the following I use `map` then `reduce`)

```
case class Point(x : Double, y : Double)
val pts = List(Point(1,3), Point(-3,2), Point(5,3))

pts.map(p => p.x).reduce( _ max _ )
```

This will return

```
res22: Double = 5.0
```

How to use a single reduce operation to get the max of `x` out? I tried the following, but didn't get what I expect.

```
pts.reduce( _.x max _.x )
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Point
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `foldLeft` to get to a double:

```
pts.foldLeft(Double.MinValue)(_ max _.x)
```

Or you can use `reduce` to keep passing a `Point` around and pull its `x` out afterwards:

```
pts.reduce((a, b) => if (a.x > b.x) a else b).x
```

Comment: Thanks it works. May you elaborate how `pts.foldLeft(Double.MinValue)(_ max _.x)` this work? Reading the code, the `MinValue` is counterintuitive as we are trying to take the max.

Comment: We want the smallest value possible to "seed" our reduce (`fold` is a `reduce` but with a default in case the collection is empty).  We start with the smallest entry possible and then take the max of the smallest value possible and our first `Point.x` entry.  Then we compare the max of that comparison with our next `Point.x` entry.  If we started with a larger value we might wind up with garbage data.  (For example, if we started out with 0 and all of our points were `-x` our "max" would be 0, not the smallest negative number in the list.)  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17408880/135978

Answer (score 3):

All these are over-complicated. Use the standard library function that does precisely what is needed here:

```
 pts.maxBy(_.x).x   //> res0: Double = 5.0
```

Or, if the example is just a toy one and the real use case is more complex, you can use `aggregate`

```
pts.aggregate(Double.MinValue)( _ max _.x , _ max _)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` and `max`

```
pts.map(_.x).reduce( (a,v) => a max v)
```

Other approaches to find the maximum in a `List[Point]` includes

```
pts.map(_.x).max
```

Comment: `pts.map(_.x).sorted.last` O(NlogN) with an extra unnecessary O(N) at the end for good measure.  Really not a good alternative...