# Difference between fold and reduce revisted

Tags: mapreduce, functional-programming, reduce, fold

I've been reading a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25158790/7337271) to [Difference between reduce and foldLeft/fold in functional programming (particularly Scala and Scala APIs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25158780/7337271) provided by [samthebest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586965/samthebest) and I am not sure if I understand all the details:

- According to the answer (`reduce` vs `foldLeft`):

  > A big big difference (...) is that reduce should be given a commutative monoid, (...)
  >
  > This distinction is very important for Big Data / MPP / distributed computing, and the entire reason why reduce even exists.

  and

  > Reduce is defined formally as part of the MapReduce paradigm,

  I am not sure how this two statements combine. Can anyone put some light on that?
- I tested different collections and I haven't seen performance difference between `reduce` and `foldLeft`. It looks like `ParSeq` is a special case, is that right?
- Do we really need order to define `fold`?

  > we cannot define fold because chunks do not have an ordering and fold only requires associativity, not commutativity.

  Why it couldn't be generalized to unordered collection?

Comment: What is there to understand? For `foldLeft` you cannot assume associativity/commutativity (no opportunity for parallelization), for `reduce` you can (trivial to parallelize). Not sure how it could be made any clearer than that. These are generic concepts, and extend beyond the perf of any collections that happen to be in the Scala standard library at any particular point in time.

Comment: @JaredSmith I think that reduce in MapReduce has different meaning than reduce in Spark or Scala collections. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK currently the only difference in scala is the seed value that may be supplied to `foldLeft`. But the point of the answer that you reference is that there *should* be a difference involving the mathematical properties of the binary operator applied to the type in question. The answers to this question should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408880/reduce-fold-or-scan-left-right

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you but I don't have any doubts about (fold|reduce)(left|right). I just don't understand a) association between reduce in Map__Reduce__ and reduce and reduce in Spark b) Why limit fold to ordered collections when conceptual it is more general

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the term *reduce* means different thing when used in the context of MapReduce and when used in the context of functional programming.

- In MapReduce, the system groups the results of the `map` function by a given key and then calls the `reduce` operation to aggregate values for each group (so `reduce` is called once for each group). You can see it as a function `(K, [V]) -> R` taking the group key `K` together with all the values belonging to the group `[V]` and producing some result.
- In functional programming, `reduce` is a function that aggregates elements of some collection when you give it an operation that can combine two elements. In other words, you define a function `(V, V) -> V` and the `reduce` function uses it to aggregate a collection `[V]` into a single value `V`.

When you want to add numbers `[1,2,3,4]` using `+` as the function, the `reduce` function can do it in a number of ways:

1. It can run from the start and calculate `((1+2)+3)+4)`
2. It can also calculate `a = 1+2` and `b = 3+4` in parallel and then add `a+b`!

The `foldLeft` operation is, by definition always proceeding from the left and so it always uses the evaluation strategy of (1). In fact, it also takes an initial value, so it evaluates something more like `(((0+1)+2)+3)+4)`. This makes `foldLeft` useful for operations where the order matters, but it also means that it cannot be implemented for unordered collections (because you do not know what "left" is).

Comment: Thank you, it confirms my understanding. The other answer is so highly upvoted I started doubting my sanity.