# spark rdd, need to reduce over (key,(tuple))

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

A previous process gave me the accumulator and count of every group in the next way:

```
val data: Array[(Int, (Double, Int))] = Array((2,(2.1463120403829962,7340)), (1,(1.4532644653720025,4280)))
```

the structure is `(groupId,(acum,count))`

now want reduce to get the sum of every tuple:

```
(k1,(a1,n1)),(k2,(a2,n2))
```

need:

```
(a1+a2),(n1+n2)
```

Sound like a simple task, So do:

```
val mainMean = groups.reduce((acc,v)=>(acc._1 + v._1,acc._2 + v._2))
```

And get:

> :33: error: type mismatch;  found   : (Double, Int) 
>   required: String
>          val mainMean = groups.reduce((acc,v)=>(acc._1 + v._1,acc._2 + v._2))

Also tried:

```
val mainMean = groups.reduce((k,(acc,v))=>(acc._1 + v._1,acc._2 + v._2))
```

and tell me: Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple2,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function

So:

```
val mainMean = groups.reduce({case(k,(acc,n))=>(k,(acc._1+n._1,acc._1+n._2))})
```

and get

> error: type mismatch;  found   : (Int, (Double, Int))  required: Int

I know it a newbie question but I am stuck on it

Comment: The previous step was `reduceByKey((acc,v)=>(acc._1 + v._1,acc._2 + v._2))`, now only must to sum the acumulators and the counts of every group, it can be do it in two step like i showed , but i want do do in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be some difficulties working with tuples. 
 
Below you can see working code, but let me explain.

```
val data = Array((2,(2.1463120403829962,7340)), (1,(1.4532644653720025,4280)))

def tupleSum(t1: (Int, (Double, Int)), t2: (Int, (Double, Int))): (Int, (Double, Int)) =
    (0,(t1._2._1 + t2._2._1, t1._2._2 + t2._2._2))

val mainMean = data.reduce(tupleSum)._2
```

We can introduce `reduce` arguments like

```
data.reduce((tuple1, tuple2) => tupleSum(tuple1, tuple2))
```

where `tuple1` is kind of accumulator. On the first iteration it takes the first value of the array, and every next value adds to the value of accumulator.

So if you want to perform reduce using pattern matching it will look like this:

```
val mainMean = data.reduce((tuple1, tuple2) => { 
  val t1 = tuple1 match { case (i, t) => t }
  val t2 = tuple2 match { case (i, t) => t }
// now t1 and t2 represents inner tuples of input tuples
  (0, (t1._1 + t2._1, t1._2 + t2._2))}
)
```

UPD. 
I rewrite previous listing adding type annotations and println statements. I hope it will help to get the point. And there is some explanation after.

```
val data = Array((3, (3.0, 3)), (2,(2.0,2)), (1,(1.0,1)))

val mainMean = data.reduce((tuple1: (Int, (Double, Int)),
                             tuple2: (Int, (Double, Int))) => {
    println("tuple1: " + tuple1)
    println("tuple2: " + tuple2)

    val t1: (Double, Int) = tuple1 match {
        case (i: Int, t: (Double, Int)) => t
    }
    val t2: (Double, Int) = tuple2 match {
        case (i: Int, t: (Double, Int)) => t
    }
    // now t1 and t2 represents inner tuples of input tuples
    (0, (t1._1 + t2._1, t1._2 + t2._2))}
)
println("mainMean: " + mainMean)
```

And the output will be:

```
tuple1: (3,(3.0,3)) // 1st element of the array
tuple2: (2,(2.0,2)) // 2nd element of the array
tuple1: (0,(5.0,5)) // sum of 1st and 2nd elements
tuple2: (1,(1.0,1)) // 3d element
mainMean: (0,(6.0,6)) // result sum
```

`tuple1` and `tuple2` type is `(Int, (Double, Int))`. We know it always be only this type, that is why we use only one case in pattern matching. We unpack tuple1 to `i: Int` and `t: (Int, Double)`. As far as we are not interested in key, we return only t. Now `t1` is representing the inner tuple of `tuple1`. The same story with `tuple2` and`t2`.

You can find more information about fold functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408880/reduce-fold-or-scan-left-right) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158780/difference-between-reduce-and-foldleft-fold-in-functional-programming-particula)

Comment: Thank you @wopqw, is exactly that i wanted, is a problem of tuple unpacking, the solution with function is easy to understand, but the pattern matching is more complicated, can you give more detailed explanation of this. I read some examples of pattern matching anonymous function, but with only one case, which is the sense of t?

Comment: @user2232395, I updated the answer.  I hope it become more clear now. Feel free to ask if something is fuzzily.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
val arr = Seq((1, (1,1)), (1, (2,2)), (2, (3,3)))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)

rdd.
    reduceByKey{ case (acc, t) => (acc._1 + t._1, acc._2 + t._2)}.
    collect
// Array((1,(3,3)), (2,(3,3)))
```