# Fold that returns intermediate results and not just the last one

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, fold

I'm looking for a function similar to `fold`, which doesn't return only the final result but all intermediate results as well.

For example with `fold` I could implement the following example:

```
val res = listOf(1,2,3).fold(0, { acc, it -> f(acc, it) })
// res = 6
```

But I'm looking for something like...

```
val res = listOf(1,2,3).foo(0, { acc, it -> f(acc, it) })
// res = listOf(1,3,6)
```

...which then would return the intermediate results instead of just the final sum.

Is there something like this `foo` function already included in Kotlins stdlib or what would be a common name for this `foo` in functional programming style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this exists in kotlin, but that's called `scan`. You could see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408881/6345611) answer for more details (not kotlin, but, since Scala influenced it *a lot*, probably you even wont see syntax differences).

Comment: Thank you, `scan` is exactly what I'm looking for. But you're right, kotlin seems to lag that (or at least not under that name). But at least I now know what I'm looking.

Comment: If it lacks it, then implement it. It's not Kotlin the language that lacks it after all, just the standard library.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: True to that! But luckily that's very easy to do in Kotlin anyways. For reference reasons: There is already exists an open issue for `scan`: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7657 (including a sample implementation).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for functional operator called `scan`.

As of Kotlin 1.4, `scan` is [present in the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/scan.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the basic `fold()`:

```kotlin
listOf(1, 2, 3).fold(listOf(0)) { acc, t -> acc + f(acc.last(), t) }
```

Complete example:

```kotlin
val f = { i: Int, j: Int -> i + j }
listOf(1, 2, 3).fold(listOf(0)) { acc, t -> acc + f(acc.last(), t) }
        .also { println(it) }
```

Prints: `[0, 1, 3, 6]`